# What is the meaning of a.s.?

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes

What is the meaning of `a.s.` behind a limit formula (I found this in a paper about stochastic processes) , or sometimes `P-a.s.`?

Comment: It means almost surely. P-a.s means almost surely with respect to probability measure P. For more details wiki out "almost sure convergence".

Comment: @GautamShenoy:  You should post that as an Answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means almost surely. P-a.s means almost surely with respect to probability measure P. For more details wiki out "almost sure convergence".

Let me give some insights: When working with convergence of sequences of random variables(in general stochastic processes), it is not necessary for convergence to happen for all $w \in \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space. Instead it is fine if the set where it doesn't converge happens over a set with measure 0, since most of the results go through. If you take a measure theory course, you will be able to appreciate this even more.

Comment: I'm a CS student with little mathematical knowledge, thank you for your advice, I will find some information about measure theory

Comment: Hopefully you have an analysis background.

Comment: Then may I ask what is `analysis background` about? Thanks

Comment: By that I mean the notion of limits, continuity, differentiability, integration. Basically first 7 chapters of "Principles of mathematical analysis", by Walter Rudin.